# Is Ionic 3 is reliable for production?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3

I am developing an application in hybrid environment, with the latest versions of Cordova, Ionic and Android, but facing a lot of serious issues. These issues might be because of the platform updation because at ionic 2 it was everything fine, after updating everything becomes useless.

Is it fine to use Ionic 3? If yes, what combinations of Cordova can we use for building application?

Comment: This **totally** depends on what kind of app you're trying to create. For example: I wanted to create an app where I can send push notifications from within the app, so called `LocalNotifications`. The current plugin is very bugged and doesn't work with ionic. So just get your requirements together and check the documentation for said functionality. But `ionic 3` is overall ready for production

Comment: I think you did not get my point @Ivaro18.

Comment: Well I made some assumptions while typing that comment yes. But those assumptions are caused by the lack of explanation in your question. You talk about having 'serious issues' without explaining them and then continue to ask if ionic 3 is ready for production. Yes generally ionic 3 is ready for production but who knows, maybe some dependencies you're using aren't compatible with ionic 3 compared to ionic 2.

Comment: anyways Thanks for your concern. I got the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ionic 3 is good to work on. We have made couple of projects in Ionic 3. Below are the versions of Ionic, Cordova and Android used.

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2                                                                                              
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
cordova           : 8.0.0
android platform version added : 7.1.0
```